# Randomize and show a given number if elements on pageload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to randomize elements on pageload - and just show 4 of them regardless on how many there are.

The closest I come is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".itembox.newcenterbox").hide();

var elements = $(".itembox.newcenterbox");
var elementCount = elements.size();
var elementsToShow = 4;
var alreadyChoosen = ",";
var i = 0;
while (i < elementsToShow) {
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * elementCount);
    if (alreadyChoosen.indexOf("," + rand + ",") < 0) {
        alreadyChoosen += rand + ",";
        elements.eq(rand).show();
        ++i;
    }
}
});
```

It works for me on my local site - but it chrashes my live site.and I can't figure out why.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: A first glance this code looks a bit weird but correct. What error do you get on the live site?

Comment: Indeed the code looks correct, thought it is using jQuery to a pointless degree here (built in js has everything needed for this in about the same length of code).

Comment: It creates some kinda loop - it makes my site load and become unresponsive - need to force quit it. Makes it hard to try to find whats going on. I dont mind trying another way if someone have a better way of doing this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your `elementCount` is less than `elementsToShow`? In this case, you will always get `rand` value between 0 and 3, and it will lead to an infinite loop.

Try the code below. Also I removed unnecessary loop iterations when you check the `rand` index.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var elements = $(".itembox.newcenterbox");
    var elementsToShow = 4;
    var i = 0;

    if(elements.length < elementsToShow) return;

    for (i = 0; i < elementsToShow; i++) {
        elements.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length), 1);
    }

    elements.hide();

});
```